# How to add animation to a image slider when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to add an animation to an image slider when a button is clicked

How do I add transitions and animations like transitions when a buttons are clicked?

my HTML

```
<section id="slider-area"\>
    <div class="container2 container"\>
        <div class="subcontainer2"\>
                <div class="slider-wrappers"\>
                    <h2>client showcase</h2>
                    <br />
                    <div class="slider2"\>
                        <img src="A-50.jpeg" />
                    </div\>
                    <br />
                    <div id="controller"\>
                    <button class="backward"\>
                    <img alt="previous client" src="left.jpg" />
                    </button\>
                    <button class="forward"\>
                    <img alt="next client" src="right.jpg" />
                    </button\>
                </div\>
            </div\>
        </div\>
    </div\>
</section\>
```

my CSS

```
.slider2 .change{
border-radius: 5px;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

my javascript

```
const slider101 = document.querySelector(".slider2 .change")

const front = document.querySelector(".forward");
const back = document.querySelector(".backward");
const collection
 = [images here]


let noor = 0;

front.addEventListener("click", function(){

  slider101.src = collection[noor];
  if(noor >= collection.length-1){
    noor = 0;
  } else {
      noor++;
  }
  slider101.src = collection[noor];
});

back.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(noor === 0){
    noor = collection.length-1;
  } else {
    noor--;
  }
  slider101.src = collection[noor];
});
```

I have been trying to add an animation to my image slider. The animation is not working.

Comment: Do I need to add a new image that is the previous one to the image and added animations?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: Thank you for trying to solve my solution but the slider you showed me was not the one is was going for

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Image Slider Automatic Animation & Button click Animation also its have dots indicators which is also clickable and when you hover on the Image Slider then it will stop

```js
Javascript Code:

//access the images
let slideImages = document.querySelectorAll('.img');
//access the next & prev buttons
let next = document.querySelector('.next');
let prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
//access the indicators 
let dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

var counter = 0;

//code for next button 
next.addEventListener('click', slideNext);

function slideNext() {
    slideImages[counter].style.animation = 'next1 0.5s ease-in forwards';
    if (counter >= slideImages.length - 1) {
        counter = 0;
    } else {
        counter++;
    }
    slideImages[counter].style.animation = 'next2 0.5s ease-in forwards';
    indicators();
}

//code for prev button
prev.addEventListener('click', slidePrev);

function slidePrev() {
    slideImages[counter].style.animation = 'prev1 0.5s ease-in forwards';
    if (counter == 0) {
        counter = slideImages.length - 1;
    } else {
        counter--;
    }
    slideImages[counter].style.animation = 'prev2 0.5s ease-in forwards';
    indicators();
}


//auto sliding 
function autoSliding() {
    deletInterval = setInterval(timer, 2000);

    function timer() {
        slideNext();
        indicators();
    }
}
autoSliding();

//stop auto sliding  when mouse is hover
const container = document.querySelector('.slide-container');
container.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    clearInterval(deletInterval);
});

//resume auto slidin when mouse is out
container.addEventListener('mouseout', autoSliding);

//add and remove active class from the indicators
function indicators() {
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
    }
    dots[counter].className += ' active';
}

//add click event to the indicator
function switchImage(currentImage) {
    currentImage.classList.add('active');
    var imageId = currentImage.getAttribute('attr');
    if (imageId > counter) {
        slideImages[counter].style.animation = 'next1 0.5s ease-in forwards';
        counter = imageId;
        slideImages[counter].style.animation = 'next2 0.5s ease-in forwards';
    } else if (imageId == counter) {
        return;
    } else {
        slideImages[counter].style.animation = 'prev1 0.5s ease-in forwards';
        counter = imageId;
        slideImages[counter].style.animation = 'prev2 0.5s ease-in forwards';
    }
    indicators();
}
```

```css
CSS Code:

.slide-container {
            border-radius: 10px;
            position: relative;
            width: 97%;
            height: 535px;
            margin: 70px 22px;
            border: 3px solid #ede6d6;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            animation: myAnimS 9s ease 1s infinite normal forwards;
        }
        
        @keyframes myAnimS {
            0%,
            100% {
                transform: translateY(0);
            }
            10%,
            30%,
            50%,
            70% {
                transform: translateY(-8px);
            }
            20%,
            40%,
            60% {
                transform: translateY(8px);
            }
            80% {
                transform: translateY(6.4px);
            }
            90% {
                transform: translateY(-6.4px);
            }
        }
        
        .slide-container .slides {
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            animation: myAnim 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
        }
        
        @keyframes myAnim {
            0% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: rotateX(70deg);
                transform-origin: center;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: rotateX(0deg);
                transform-origin: center;
            }
        }
        
        .slide-container .slides img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
        
        .slide-container .slides img:not(.active) {
            top: 0;
            left: -100%;
        }
        
        span.next,
        span.prev {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            padding: 14px;
            color: #eee;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            transition: 0.5s;
            border-radius: 3px;
            user-select: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            /* z-index: 1; */
        }
        
        span.next {
            right: 20px;
        }
        
        span.prev {
            left: 20px;
        }
        
        span.next:hover,
        span.prev:hover {
            background-color: #ede6d6;
            opacity: 0.5;
            color: #222;
        }
        
        .dots-container {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 5px;
            /* z-index: 3; */
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
        
        .dots-container .dot {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            margin: 0px 2px;
            border: 3px solid #bbb;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: background-color 0.6 ease;
        }
        
        .dots-container .active {
            background-color: grey;
        }
        
        @keyframes next1 {
            from {
                left: 0%;
            }
            to {
                left: -100%;
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes next2 {
            from {
                left: 100%;
            }
            to {
                left: 0%;
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes prev1 {
            from {
                left: 0%;
            }
            to {
                left: 100%;
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes prev2 {
            from {
                left: -100%;
            }
            to {
                left: 0%;
            }
        }
```

```html
Html Code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Home</title>
    
</head>

<body>

 <div class="slide-container">
            <div class="slides">
                <img src="assets/img1.jpg" alt="" class="active img">
                <img src="assets/img2.jpg" alt="" class="img">
                <img src="assets/img3.jpg" alt="" class="img">
                <img src="assets/img4.jpg" alt="" class="img">
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <span class="next">&#10095;</span>
                <span class="prev">&#10094;</span>
            </div>

            <div class="dots-container">
                <div class="dot active" id="active" attr='0' onclick="switchImage(this)"></div>
                <div class="dot" attr='1' onclick="switchImage(this)"></div>
                <div class="dot" attr='2' onclick="switchImage(this)"></div>
                <div class="dot" attr='3' onclick="switchImage(this)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I ran your code snippet and got an error

Comment: Errors you get because of Javascript Code:, CSS Code: and Html Code: labels in snippet. Delete them and run again it should work fine @AunZaidi

Comment: I'm still getting an error but this time about the images not being found do you want me to add the images? thank you for trying to solve my question

Comment: Thank you for your solution but it seems like this slider only works on very small images but it is better than before. Can you tell me how to stop the image slider from going up and down it is very annoying and disturbing. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop an image slider from moving, you can use JavaScript or jQuery to pause the slideshow when it reaches the last slide. Here's an example using jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slides = $('.slides');
  var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,3000);

  function nextSlide(){
    slides.animate({'margin-left':'-=100%'},1000,function(){
      currentSlide++;
      if (currentSlide === slides.length) {
        clearInterval(slideInterval);
      }
    });
  }
});
```